# Plot an error ellipse at the tip of a vector arrow

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.12 and I would like to plot **an error ellipse at the tip of a vector arrow**.

I have plotted GNSS velocity vectors in a map and now I would like to plot the error associated to the vector. How could I do it ?

I have tried to add an ellipse in the symbology, but not sure how to locate it at the tip of the vector arrow. The idea is to produce a similar map as the one below. The arrows indicate the displacement direction and velocity (vector length) of Iberia respect a fixed Africa from GNSS measurements and the ellipse the associated error.

The origin of the vector is the location of the **GNSS station** and the arrow tip location depends on the vector length. Is at that arrow tip that the ellipse would be located.

[image]

Comment: maybe a picture would help ?

Comment: are you sure you want an **ellipse** ? i only see **circles** on your picture ... do u have variables controling major and minor axis of the ellipse ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **geometry generator** on the symbology tab of the layer properties. There is a *make_ellipse* function. You need the center of the ellipse, the semi-major and semi-minor axis length and the azimuth of the semi-major axis. For example if you would like to have the ellipse at the endpoint of a polyline you sould enter the following expression:

```
make_ellipse( make_point($x_at(-1), $y_at(-1)), "major", "minor", "azimut")
```

*$x_at(-1)* and *$y_at(-1)* return the coordinates of the last point of the linestring, *make_point* creates a point geometry from the two coordinates.
Here I supposed the "major", "minor" and "azimut" columns of the attribute table contain the ellipse data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zoltan! I am plotting the ellipse but its origin is located at the beginning of the arrow. I have also tried $x_at(0) and $y_at(0) but nothing changes. Maybe is because I am plotting the vector arrow using the vector field marker symbol function. I will look for some info to know how vector field marker works.

Comment: Looking for more information about vector field I have found the plugin "Vector field layer manager" that makes exactly what I needed, plots vectors and ellipse errors associated to this vectors. Thanks for your help and time.